# NullPointer exception when trying to pass a value from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to implement an `onItemClicklister()` in which when an item is clicked, the text values are carried over from one activity to another. Below is the code snippet.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
```

Next Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
        String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
        String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);

//         Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
        TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

        lblName.setText(name);
        lblCost.setText(cost);
        lblDesc.setText(description);
    }
```

But it throws a

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eve_haps/com.example.eve_haps.SingleMenuItemActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at com.example.eve_haps.SingleMenuItemActivity.onCreate(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:32)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(  626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

I dont seem know what the problem is.Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why did you put in comment your setContentView method ?

Comment: What is a 32 line of SingleMenuItemActivity.java file?

Comment: Try to put log in your first activity's onItemClick function & display name,cost,description String variable value in log so you can come to know that if the value is fetch or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un Comment following code line from **SingleMenuItemActivity's** `onCreate()`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);
```

I think your `TextViews` are null.

And **NullPointerException** comes from these lines,

```
lblName.setText(name);
lblCost.setText(cost);
lblDesc.setText(description);
```

Comment: Thanks.Serious blunder. My Mistake